# How do I find the key of a value in a dictionary that closest to, but not more than, a variable?

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary, d.

```
d = {"x": 4, "r" : 9, "p" : 18, "v" : 20}
```

and I have a variable, i. How do I find the key of the value that's closest to, but not more than, i?

for example, if i is 5, the function would return "x", but if i is 19, the function would return "p".

The only thing i can think of to start is to use a for loop.

Comment: How would you change a single value in your dict?  How would you do one thing for each item in your dict?

Comment: My apologies, I thought that subtracting the variable would give me the result I want, but that would change all the values in the dict, and the greatest value would be the same key. I updated my question to fit my new dilemma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
d = {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 4}
x = 2

# subtract from all values
for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = v - x

# get the key with the largest value
largest = max(d, key=lambda k: d[k])
```

Given you're applying an integer offset (subtraction in this case) to all values, the largest key will be the same before and after subtraction, so it doesnt make a difference

EDIT:

For your revised question, try this:

```
d = {"x": 4, "r" : 9, "p" : 18, "v" : 20}
x = 19
closest = min(d, key=lambda k: abs(d[k] - x))  # returns 'p'
```

It just returns the key with the smallest difference value between `x` and your values. However, I'm not sure how you want to handle situations where multiple keys fit your criterion

You mentioned a function, not that its needed as its a one liner, but its easy to convert the above:

```
def find_closest(d, x):
    return min(d, key=lambda k: abs(d[k] - x))

closest = find_closest(d, 8)  # 'r'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to generate a new dictionary without `x` with just one line of code.

```
my_dict = {'one' : 1, 'two' :2, 'five' : 5, 'three' : 3}
bad = 5

output = {k: v for k, v in my_dict.items() if v != bad}

print( max(output.values()) )
```

[Here it is in action](https://repl.it/NTgE/1).